# How to fix "ValueError: Series.replace cannot use dict-like to_replace and non-None value "

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to use this following line of code to replace the retirees' incorrect days values ​​with 9000, but I get the error in the title. This is the line:
 `df.replace(df.loc[(df['days_employed']>100000) & (df['income_type']=='retiree')], 9000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer to the [LOC](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) documentation, section 'setting values'

the second parameter to the loc is the column to update

```
# replace the col-to-update, with the column you like to update
df.loc[(df['days_employed']>100000) & (df['income_type']=='retiree'),'col-to-update']= 9000
```

Comment: you can do it without replace. updated the answer.check now